# Unable to run metadata_startup_script in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a terraform script

```
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default3" {
  disk     = google_compute_disk.default2.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.default.id
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "test"
  machine_type = "custom-8-16384"
  zone         = "asia-south1-a"

  tags = ["foo", "bar"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "centos-cloud/centos-7"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      
    }
  }
    metadata_startup_script = <<-EOF
  echo "hello
  you" > /test.txt
  echo "help
  me" > /test2.txt
  EOF


  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "default2" {
  name  = "test-disk"
  type  = "pd-balanced"
  zone  = "asia-south1-a"
  image = "centos-7-v20210609"
  size =  100
}
```

Now I want to run metadata_startup_script, but it won`t execute. Resources are created but the script is not executed. How can I run this script?
Basically I have a big bash script. How can I run this script in GCP machine?

Comment: If your script doesn't seem like getting executed, try `journalctl -u google-startup-scripts`. Also you might want to add `set -x` to the script.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large script to run, I recommend you to use [startup-script-url](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux#metadata-keys) to load the startup script from GCS instead of having it hardcoded in the terraform.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "test"
  machine_type = "custom-8-16384"
  zone         = "asia-south1-a"

  metadata = {
    startup-script-url = "gs://<bucket>/path/to/file"
  }
 ...
 ...
}
```

Else, for your current issue, I also recommend to use the metadata

```
  metadata = {
    startup-script = <<-EOF
  echo "hello
  you" > /test.txt
  echo "help
  me" > /test2.txt
  EOF
  }
```

Comment: Excuse me, it was obvious in my head!! You have to use it in the resource compute engine instance. See my update and let me know if it's clearer!

Comment: but I want to run a local script instead of URL

Comment: and i also did like generate a ssh key (public and private using mobaxtrem) and then use metadata like this  metadata = {
    ssh-keys = "${rohan}:${file(C:/user/rohan/desktop/public)}"
  }  and also in connection parameter provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host        = google_compute_address.static.address
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = var.user 
      timeout     = "500s"
      private_key = file(C:/user/rohan/desktop/public.ppk)
    } but using this also not able to execute script

Comment: No worries, you can use the second code example where you don't use a file but directly the code in the medata key pair. I just tested, it worked well :)

Comment: but i have a big script around 50+ line so it is not best practice so can you tell me how do i ssh into my gcp machine

Comment: You can't SSH with Terraform. The startup script is perfect to finalize the set up of your VM after the deployment. If you need more feature on the VM directly, you need to use other tools, such as Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

You may find documentation on running startup scripts useful;

Startup script can be ran using three methods:

- local file
- from metadata
- cloud storage bucket

Even ~50 line script can be run using all the methods ([they can be up to 256 KB or more for GCS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts)). If you can't / don't want to use local file nor put the script in the metadata while creating a new VM you can store it in a GCS bucket.

If that doesn't answer your needs then using ansible as [guillaume blaquiere said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206325/unable-to-run-metadata-startup-script-in-terraform#comment120556141_68210222) is a very good choice.